How many review tasks
I used to be able to see how many reviews I had completed from each of the review queues. But I can't find that information anywhere anymore.
Is it still possible to see those statistics?

I tried, and as of this writing, the following links work:
go to Review queues, e.g. https://quant.stackexchange.com/review
Click on "Stats" under one of the queues, e.g. https://quant.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/stats
On the right, it will say "Total: $\boldsymbol{nn}$".
